# How to extract MULTIPLE classes from MODIS?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Let's say I am trying to extract MORE THAN ONE LULC class (e.g. cropland + crop mosaic) from the MODIS global lulc. How it can be done?

I found that:

```
var class1 = image.eq(class1)
var class2 = image.eq(class2)
```

allows us to select one class at a time and that:

```
ee.Image.cat([class1, class2, class3])
```

allows us to concatenate them into a single Image.

However it changes the structure of the Image, adding multiple bands instead of a single band with all classes. Plus, we lose the original class code.

I also tried using

```
image.or(image.eq(class1), image.eq(class2))
```

and it doesn't work as well.

Basically, I want to select all classes that I am interested in, but keeping them in a single band, preferably with the same original class code.

As far as I got:

```
var ecoregions = ee.FeatureCollection('RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017');
var cerrado = ecoregions.filterMetadata('ECO_NAME', 'equals', 'Cerrado')

var cover = ee.Image('MODIS/051/MCD12Q1/2012_01_01').select('Land_Cover_Type_1')
.clip(cerrado.geometry());

var cover13 = cover.eq(13)
var cover15 = cover.eq(15)   

var combined = ee.Image.cat([cover13, cover15])

Map.addLayer(combined, {min: 0, max: 2},'Two classes');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For preserving classes and original color palette of MODIS product (in only one band), you can try following [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f6fb44ac197e711424268cd623f55fb7). Your selected classes (13 and 15) represent small or nonexistent areas (for Snow and ice, class 15) so, I chose, instead, following three classes values: 2 (Evergreen Broadleaf forest), 9 (Savannas) and 13 (Urban and built-up).

```
var ecoregions = ee.FeatureCollection('RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017');
var cerrado = ecoregions.filterMetadata('ECO_NAME', 'equals', 'Cerrado');

var cover = ee.Image('MODIS/051/MCD12Q1/2012_01_01')
  .select('Land_Cover_Type_1')
  .clip(cerrado.geometry());
  
print(cover);

Map.centerObject(cover, 5);

var added_areas = cover.updateMask(cover.eq(2)
  .or(cover.eq(9))
  .or(cover.eq(13)));

print(added_areas);

Map.addLayer(added_areas, {}, 'three classes');
Map.addLayer(cover, {}, 'cover');
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, I got following result for all 18 classes in cerrado area.

[image]

Selecting only three classes result is as follows:

[image]

**Editing Note:**

I slightly modified above code for calculating areas in an arbitrary polygon on **added_areas**. Code snippet is as follows:

```
var counts = added_areas.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry: polygon,
  scale: resolution
}).get('Land_Cover_Type_1');

print('counts:',counts);
```

Complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0c644efad232854f3a7b3e5df548e2b3).

After running it in GEE console editor, I got following result:

[image]

Areas values were printed in Console Tab (red rectangle). You can create a dictionary for printing classes names (Evergreen Broadleaf forest, Savannas and Urban and built-up) instead classes values (2, 9, 13).

Comment: Awesome answer @xulik, thank you! I have a question. When we use updateMask the classes we did not select are still in the image, but just hidden or do they get actually excluded? 

I want to know this because I will calculate the area of each class for a set of polygons, and I wanted to reduce computational time by allowing only the classes of my interest to be counted/measured. Does it make sense? Thank you, again, I am sorry for not being more specific earlier.

Comment: You can see my **Editing Note** where it was placed an example with an arbitrary polygon for areas calculation. Only present classes were taken in account (excluding masked pixels).

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much! I really appreciate the time you invested on it!